# Downloading images from the gallery in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i need to import images from the default gallery to the storage in sd card that I use for the app. Is it possible?

Comment: import images from default gallery to the storage?

Comment: my dear images are already stored in SD-card if they gets displayed in gallery then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Intent to have the user pick an image from the default gallery.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri path = getTempUri("/mnt/sdcard/yourfolder");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, path);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, filenameInt);
```

This will save the image picked by the user to the `path` you specified. There are some more options like cropping and scaling:

```
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true")
                         .putExtra("aspectX", 4)
                         .putExtra("aspectY", 3)
                         .putExtra("outputX", 800)
                         .putExtra("outputY", 600)
                         .putExtra("scale", true);
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you're aiming for though.

Comment: sorry for responding late. I will try it and inform you after that.